# How to deprecate a sitemap.xml file?

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap, sitemap.xml

I am moving a dozen site pages, originally hosted at ://will.retire.com, to ://new.site.com/folder1.

For every page at ://will.retire.com/*, I am creating redirects which redirect to the corresponding page, now found at ://new.site.com/folder1/*.

What is the appropriate action to take for the site map found at ://will.retire.com/sitemap.xml ?  Should this page now redirect to a new sitemap.xml, found at either ://new.site.com/sitemap.xml or ://new.site.com/folder1/sitemap.xml?

Since all of the pages at ://will.retire.com are now responding with redirects, will any crawler even try to access the sitemap.xml?  If this is true, then I can simply remove ://will.retire.com/sitemap.xml.

Thank you for taking a look.  For any answer, references appreciated.

Comment: By default, crawlers, at least Google's, look for the path to the XML sitemap/s in the robots.txt file. Now you need to do two things. First, make sure your XML sitemaps only contain the new URLs. Second, make sure you have the Sitemap directive in your robots.txt file to point to the absolute URL of the XML sitemap. For example: 
Sitemap: https://new.site.com/sitemap.xml